# Restricting access to resource elements

Tags: rest, ws-security

What is the best way to restrict access to some of the elements of a resource returned within a RESTFul service call? The user will be authenticated and authorized (by role) for a resource, but I would like more granularity on granting/restricting access of the returned elements ... almost an explicit role-based data filter.

This question is the same as: 
[How to model restrictions on data visible on resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228087/how-to-model-restrictions-on-data-visible-on-resources)

but I would rather not filter in the application.  Since 3 years have past since the original request ... any updates in this area?